# How to find index path of an item in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Ok so I have a collection view and am trying to find the indexpath of an item because I need to delete an item at a certain index path. For example This is hard to explain sorry. Ok so in my collection view, I have made a constant count = mycollectionview.numberof items at section 1, there is only one section. Here is some code I currently have, you will see i have some code to check if the item is above number 3 or equal to.

```
     var currentImage = 0
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    var iti = //indexpathofitem

    let count = myCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 1)

    let x = floor(myCollectionView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width)
    if Int(x) != currentImage {
        currentImage = Int(x)
        print(currentImage)
    }
}
```

please ask any questions you have in the comments, and I will answer them, sorry if this is confusing. Just need to find indexpath of item in collectionview.  *horizontal scrolling, paging is enabled and image takes up the whole cell.*

Comment: use this method -: 
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)

Comment: have you checked [`.indexPathForItem(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618030-indexpathforitem) or [`.indexPath(for cell:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618094-indexpath)?

Comment: if there is only 1 section, this line doesn't make sense: `let count = myCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 1)`. Section indexing is zero-based. Section 0 = first section, section 1 = second section, and so on.

Comment: yea i know just saw that lol

Comment: Are you trying to delete the third from last item?

Comment: no I am trying to delete an item that is 2 back that the user is currently on, so img 1 img 2 and img3, if user is img 3 delete img1.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say you have the index path and you want to delete the item two cells before the index path that you have. Is this correct?

Comment: yes that is correct, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139097/discussion-between-taylor-m-and-user7424546).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new `IndexPath` instance using an initializer.

Check out the documentation for [`IndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath). You'll see you can create a new instance like this:

```
let indexPathOfLastItem: IndexPath //which you have

let indexPathOfItemToDelete = IndexPath(item: indexPathOfLastItem.item - 2, section: 0)
//may need to adjust the section or item values to fit your needs
```

The type of both parameters is `Int`. Create the index path you need by using the desired item number and section of the item you want to delete in the initializer.

Comment: what about my initialization of iti?

Comment: ah i see. `ini` is your index path. you'll need logic to figure out the cell you want to delete and place that in the parameters.